# StackExchange.Redis: No connection is available to service this operation. UnableToConnect on HOST:PORT/Interactive

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I am trying to connect REDIS database (GCP-memorystore-Redis) from C#. While set values to Redis, I'm getting exception like:

**No connection is available to service this operation**. UnableToConnect on *10.0.0.2*:*6379*/*Interactive*, Initializing, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 10s ago, last-write: 10s ago, unanswered-write: 115s ago, keep-alive: 180s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: **2.0.519.65453**; IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=1,Max=32767), Local-CPU: n/a

I am using **StackExchange.Redis** version:2.0.519

Code:

```
               IDatabase redisDB;
                try {
                    ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{host}:{port},resolvedns=1,abortConnect=False,keepAlive=180,connectTimeout=10000");
                   
                    redisDB = redis.GetDatabase();
                    
                    if(redisDB==null)
                    {
                     **//Getting Error**
                      var messageId = redisDB.StreamAdd("event_stream", "foo_name", "bar_value");
                     //redisDB.StringSet("RedisKey", "RedisValue");
                    }
                  }
```

(or) I am also trying to set values by using below code as well. (getting same issue)

```
redisDB.StringSet("RedisKey", "RedisValue");
```

could you please help on this.

Comment: well, can it connect? the `abortConnect=False` is sometimes useful, but in this case I'd say "take that away for now", so that if it can't connect: it stops sooner. Does redis-cli connect successfully? Is there TLS involved here? Note: I've seen "redis-like" databases fail to implement the full nature of redis successfully - I haven't explicitly tests against memorystore, I'd need to see if they can offer a free service for me to test again (frankly: I'm not paying my own money to provide free support)

Comment: @MarcGravell : I am getting error at redisDB.StringSet("RedisKey", "RedisValue").  Not getting error at redis.GetDatabase(); So, it means connected successfully with Redis. Am I ?

Comment: `GetDatabase` does almost nothing; it doesn't talk to the server; the interesting operations are `Connect`, and `GetString` - but you *told* `Connect` to just pretend it connected fine, when you added `abortConnect=False`. Long story short (too late): no, nothing in the code suggests that you have "connected successfully with Redis", and the exception strongly suggests that you have not

Comment: Please, indicate from WHERE you are trying to connect to REDIS.
Connecting from Compute Engine is different than connecting from App Engine or Kubernetes https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#whats_next

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this *might* be mostly a formatting/concatenation issue, in which case the simplest approach is: **don't do that**. There is a strongly typed object model that makes it very hard to get wrong:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationOptions {
    EndPoints = {
        new DnsEndPoint(host, port),
        // new IPEndPoint(host, port), // <== or this if 'host' is an IPAddress
    },
    ResolveDns = true,
    AbortOnConnectFail = false,
    KeepAlive = 180,
    ConnectTimeout = 10000,
};
var muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(config);
```

Internally, if you give it a `string`, the first thing it is going to do is parse the `string` to create exactly the above, so you might as well just go direct!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your variable "host" in ConnectionMultiplexer connectionstring isn't correct. Look at your exception "UnableToConnect on IPAddress:6379/Interactive". So your variable "port" is correct and it has value 6379. Perhaps you have wrong conversion of your "host" variable to string. So you have in it type of variable (IPAddress) instead of real value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here IPAddress means, I am passing "my redis servier ip (10.0.0.4) " so I am getting error like "UnableToConnect on 10.0.0.4:6379/Interactive"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to connect to a local redis connection?
Anyways, I don't think my suggestion is going to work but I felt like replying anyway.
I had the same issue when I was trying to connect to my Azure Cache for Redis.

I solved it by simply putting `sslprotocols=tls12` inside the connection string.
Then it looked something like this: `azure.cache.for.redis.conn.string:6380,password:foobar,ssl=true,sslprotocols=tls12,abortConnect=false`.

I hope you've already fixed it, otherwise I hope this may be of good help :).